# ghc-mod template generation (M-t) not working

Tags: completion, haskell-mode

I've been following this [Emacs+Haskell tutorial](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md#insertion-commands) and I'm going through the [Insertion Commands](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md#insertion-commands) section.

With Emacs 24.4.1, GHC 7.10.1 and [ghc-mod master build](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod), I've managed to get `C-u M-t` to work, so it generates implementations for both `instance Eq ExampleType where` and `maybeMap :: Maybe a -> (a -> b) -> Maybe b`

However, I'm now trying to get `maybeMap x f = _maybeMap_body` to expand, so I position myself on top of `x`, then execute `M-t` but nothing happens. The status bar indicates `Nothing to be done`.

Any idea what it's wrong here or how to debug it further? Could it be a bug?

**NOTE** The reason I'm using `ghc-mod` master is because with updated Cabal 1.22 and GHC 7.8 I was having [this issue](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/429). Once I updated to GHC 7.10, I was having [this other issue](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/437), so ended up having to build/install `master` `ghc-mod` to get it to work...